# How to Send Push Notifications to Separate Android devices Using WCF Without Using 3rd Party Services?

Tags: android, cordova, wcf, push-notification, background-service

Why is it so damn hard to find a reliable solution for sending push notifications on your own? I need a solid solution for sending close-to-real-time notifications to separate Android devices using WCF.

I should not have to rely on 3rd party notification services like Google's FCM. I should be able to have a notification pushed to a user's device without their application running in the foreground and have that application open when the user selects that notification. Even when the phone reboots, the phone should still be able to process your push notifications without needing to start your app first.

Have any of you Pros accomplished this yet? If so, show us the code because there are way too many half-baked solutions out there that are either too old or never actually worked.

I'm using Cordova through Intel's XDK, but I don't care what environment you're using, just show us something that actually works.

Thanks

Comment: You will not get the reliability of FCM if you roll your own solution. Google Play Services runs as a system service and wont be killed by the OS. Anything you create will be able to be killed by the OS. FCM also has the ability to wake your device from Doze mode and any solution your run wont be able to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use Cordova cross platform solutions for this. Either use native IDEs per platform or use cross platform solutions that translate a common code base into native code per platform.